# Working with jenkins credentials

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, credentials, jenkins-scriptler

I want to know how to Create the credentials that can be used by Jenkins and by jobs running in Jenkins to connect to 3rd party services.

Comment: The answer is 42. Can you tell witch 3rd party services you want to access with Jenkins? Otherwise this question will get at least no answers.

Comment: @LucasF, I've created the credentials for all build users in Jenkins. They are used in Git plugin. Now don't know how to use them to upload artifacts to Nexus.

Comment: I was able to paste in a token from GitHub in the Secret text Credentials.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should specify which 3rd party service you will work on.
Below is an example of credentials with **bitbucket**

I am now working with Jenkins ver. 1.568.
By default, there's **Credentials** feature. So, if you want to add a credential, just click on **Add Credentials**. For example, I'd like to add **SSH Username with password**, so I can use it in checking out code from bitbucket

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Credentials plugin - provides a centralized way to define credentials that can be used by your Jenkins instance, plugins and build jobs.

Credentials Binding plugin - allows you to configure your build jobs to inject credentials as environment variables.

The third party plugins need to be installed in your Jenkins instance. For example, [Assembla Auth Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Assembla+Auth+Plugin) allows you to authenticate to an Assembla repository.

Which 3rd party services are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **SSH Username with private key** you can simply use **username with password** option

Comment: The password is printed as plaintext in the Jenkins node's temp directory. I was spooked when I first discovered this, so I decided to go with the SSH username / private key option.