# docker container as build slave for jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have installed Jenkins and docker in same machine Ubuntu.

- Ubuntu 17.10
- Jenkins ver. 2.73.3
- Docker version 17.09.0-ce.

I am trying to set up jenkin   docker containers as slaves for running my automation test suite.

I was able to correctly, setup the docker plugin in Jenkins for spinning up docker containers and added a docker template with a image that i created for setting up docker enviroment.

The image has been built on docker hosted in Ubuntu.

Problem is now when i run a job from Jenkins. It gives a error message
(pending—Jenkins doesn’t have label docker-slave)

[Jenkins pending image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyqjQ.png)

When I check the Jenkins logs in Ubuntu machine I see the following error message

```
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException: {"message":"pull access 
denied, "message":may require 'docker login'"}
```

In the ubuntu machine, i have already given done docker login.

The image that i am trying to build containers from is locally on ubuntu, not pushed to any repository, so why is trying to pull the image.

Also, what is the permission issue that i need to resolve. When build a job, from jenkins, its the jenkins user building the container. Do I need to add something else there.

Answer (score 0):

In your Jenkinsfile you can use credentials with the [credentials plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin):

```
    // Login to registry
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'YOUR_ID_AD_DEFINED_IN_JENKINS', passwordVariable: 'PASS', usernameVariable: 'USER')]) {
        sh "docker login --username=$USER --password=$PASS your.registry.here.com"
    }

    // Build with correct pom version
    sh "docker build -t your.registry.here.com/your_image_here/your_image_name:${POM_VERSION} ."

    // Push
    sh "docker push your.registry.here.com/your_image_here/your_image_name:${POM_VERSION}"

    //pull
    sh "docker pull your.registry.here.com/your_image_here/your_image_name:${POM_VERSION}"
```

The `${POM_VERSION}` is just a rip from my own code and can ofcourse be any version you like

you also need to define the credentials in your Jenkins server. A description can be found here [Working with jenkins credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400051/working-with-jenkins-credentials)

Comment: thanks @Ivonet for the response. Which Jenkinsfile are you referring to. I do not have any specific jenkins file in my configuration.

Comment: Ah that was an assumption of mine, sorry.  Then I would promote start using one :-) This way you can configure Jenkins from within your project.

Answer (score -1):

Check your docker template configuration and select "Never pool" for "pool strategy".